# Is this possible to add multiple image type in TCPDF

Tags: php, opencart, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to make PDF file from a form and email that file to User through mail function of open cart.
I have a custom form which takes image through file upload i store that image through post method and pass that variable to tcpdfimage function like this.

```
 $pdf->Image($Image, 32, 160, 30, 30, 'GIF');
```

As u can see that its file type is GIF At the moment.
If i upload a png image it wont show in my pdf. Is there any way i can upload any type of image??

Comment: I would recommend mpdf, it has more features and is flexible and I assume it supports all of the formats.

Comment: I cant shift to any other i used DOMPDF first it was perfect but for digital signatures i have to use TCPDF but cant shift now.

Comment: I see, any other way is to use html and append it using mpdf

Comment: Is there any way i can use conditions for example if image type=gif than this pdf->image(); else thispdf->image()

Comment: not sure, that is why commenting )

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by not defining any type in it.

Old:     $pdf->Image($Image, 32, 160, 30, 30, 'GIF');

New:     $pdf->Image($Image, 32, 160, 30, 30, '');